# Check Value Before Showing In Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a model like this:

```
   public class product
    {
       public int id;
       public string name;
       public bool show;
    }
```

Also I have a list with this model:

```
 List<product> list;
```

bind:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
```

Each item of 'list' that have this condition:

```
if (product.show == false)
```

shouldn't display in Datagrid.

Please Help Me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
List<product> sortedList = list.Where(item => item.show != false).ToList();
dataGrid.ItemsSource =sortedList;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this :

```
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = list.Where(ro => ro.show != false).ToList();
```